# Não consigo instalar nenhum pacote no RStudio!

Tags: r, instalador, packages

Quando abro a opção `Packages`, no console aparece essa frase:

```
Aviso: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1*
```

Mesmo tentando instalar, clicando em `Install`, e posteriormente abrindo a caixa para colocar o nome do pacote, primeiro, quando coloco a primeira letra do pacote não aparece as opções, e quando escrevo o nome todo do pacote, por exemplo, `agricolae`, aparece a seguinte mensagem no console:

```
> install.packages("agricolae")

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/sori_/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)*
```

E assim acontece com todos os pacotes que tento instalar.

Comment: A versão atual do R é 4.0.2, por favor atualize o seu R. Se por algum motivo não o puder fazer, então terá que instalar os pacotes manualmente. Descarregue as versões arquivadas dos pacotes que pretende instalar e siga as instruções das [respostas a uma pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source). Tem também que ter o [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), veja também este [post do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022977/rtools-is-required-to-build-r-packages-but-is-not-currently-installed).

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! Poderia me informar como eu consigo atualizar, porfavor? Porque já desinstalei e intalei novamente, e não resolveu o problema, há outra forma de atualizar? Gostaria de tentar esta primeiro opção primeiro. Obrigada!!

Comment: você está em que sistema operacional?

Comment: Uso o Windows 10

Comment: Já desinstalou e instalou o quê? O R? Não é preciso desinstalar, se está em Windows basta [descarregar o binário do R 4.0.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) e instalar a partir dele. A seguir descarregue e instale o Rtools seguindo o link do meu primeiro comentário. Os pacotes devem agora instalar normalmente. Nota: só precisa do Rtools se tiver que instalar a partir do código fonte, o que deverá ser a excepção, a regra é o CRAN ter binários para Windows.